# Reset password of a user in Google Apps

Tags: google-admin-sdk

How to reset password of a Google App user using Google App script/Python/Java script.

I know it can be done using GAM, I want to know if its possible through above languages.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update#request

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you update your user account.

Here is some code when you create user account.

```
{
"primaryEmail": "liz@example.com",
"name": {
"givenName": "Elizabeth",
"familyName": "Smith"
},
"suspended": false,
"password": "new user password",
"hashFunction": "SHA-1",
"changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
"ipWhitelisted": false,
"ims": [
{
```

To change the password just [update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user) your user account.

```
{
"primaryEmail": "liz@example.com",
"name": {
"givenName": "Liz",
"familyName": "Smith"
},
"suspended": false,
"password": "updated password",
"hashFunction": "SHA-1",
"changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
"ipWhitelisted": false,
"ims": [
{
```

You need to set the "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true, in order to change the password.

> NOTE: A password is required for new user accounts. If a hashFunction
>   is specified, the password must be a valid hash key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I believe this is JSON code..I need to reset the password using Google Appscript..I want to do it similar to below code-             AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource, userKey).password        Is this possible..Can you please tell me what does userKey and resource indicates.

Comment: userKey - Identifies the user in the API request. The value can be the user's primary email address, alias email address, or unique user ID. For the resource you can check this [page.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource-representations)

Comment: Thanks for the help..Now i got to know to reset the password of a Google App account..Thanks a lot

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify some things. For instance, when you update a password using `.patch()` API call, you only specify fields you change - not the whole user object. Also SHA1 for passwords, while still mostly collision-resistant as opposed to already broken MD5, isn't really recommended in 2022, especially when not salted.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer, while actually *partially* true, contains some wrong assumptions and uses plain old SHA1, which is actually discouraged now in 2022, and since my edits were rejected as *too substantial* and the question doesn't have a proper answer yet, I'll write my own answer.

You can use `patch` semantics for exactly what you're trying to do - you don't need to provide a fully-populated `User` object for that, just the fields you actually change - in your case, only the **new password details**, omitting any user fields you aren't changing in the process.

For instance, this would be the correct payload if you want to change a password to `Testpassw0rd1` (assuming your app will use a salt string of `Usesomesalthere1` and SHA-256 based password hashing, which is considered a safe algorithm):

```json
{
    "password": "$5$Usesomesalthere1$F8UxCaJUKHYgoZUY01YRiogSXXRquSmFuTHcpFOVrD7",
    "hashFunction": "crypt"
}
```

(Yes, that's the **entire** payload you'd want to send to the `patch` method endpoint for your desired user.)

A proper `password` value for any string you want you can obtain from libc `crypt()` function, using `$5$your_salt_value$` as the second parameter (replace `your_salt_value` with whatever you use in your app - you just need to have it consistent with the value used in `password` JSON parameter, can't have it different in both places or the resulting password won't work at all).